# ASP.NET Loading images to my page.aspx causing some weird errors ( sometimes! )

Tags: asp.net, image, load, photo

as you can guess by my Title, I am loading Players from my database (Microsoft SQL Server 2012) to my Players.aspx page, and ofcourse every player has a photo..

And what is happening when I'm trying to load my Players.aspx..? Weird errors are happening, one after another, that's really weird.

I will explain it more detailed:

I'm loading like 100 players in same time (still no paging), so that means I'm loading 100 photos to my page at once, so I guess I encumber my page and that caused issue, then I changed my stored procedure which is returning me **players from database** to `Select TOP (10)` so I reduced number of players which should load in my page, but issues repated over and over, and when I commented part where I am getting image, everything works well, so I really don't understand why is this happening, and why my app keeps breaking when my images are loaded with rest of attributes...

And I have to say that issues will not happen everytime, for example I run app - hitting F5 - DEBUG, everything is fine, I did it again, boom boom, and so on...

Here is my code - Players.aspx -code behind page where I'm loading my players with photos.

```
  public partial class Players : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Form.DefaultButton = this.btnsearch.UniqueID;

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                var currentClub = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                var currentClubID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

                if (SecurityServices.IsAuthorized(currentClub) == true)
                {
                    repeaterPlayers.DataSource = DAPlayers.SelectTop10Players(); //Before it was SelectALL()
                    repeaterPlayers.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    var club = DAPlayers.GetClubByName(currentClub);
                    repeaterPlayers.DataSource = DAPlayers.SelectPlayersByClubID(club.ClubID);
                    repeaterPlayers.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }


    }
```

**And here is Players.aspx**

```
  <table class="table table-hover" style="margin-top: 50px; background-color: white;">
    <tr>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>Photo</th>
    </tr>
    <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterPlayers" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repeaterPlayers_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("FirstName") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("LastName") %></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="imageTest" runat="server" style="width: 60px; height: 30px;" ImageUrl='<%#"~/ImageHandler.ashx?id="+Eval("PlayerID") %>' 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

And as I said if I comment this part  everything will work really fine! I will never face any error !: (code below, about images loading)

```
 <asp:Image ID="imageTest" runat="server" style="width: 60px; height: 30px;" ImageUrl='<%#"~/ImageHandler.ashx?id="+Eval("PlayerID") %>'
```

And here is my ImageHandler.ashx code:

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        int playerID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["id"]);
        Player newPlayer =DAPlayers.GetByPlayerID(playerID);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(newPlayer.Photo);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And here are the issues I am facing when I load also Image from database:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I must say it once again, that is not happening everytime I am trying to load my players into Players.aspx page, but it happens pretty often!

And code is really simple so I can't figure out why is that happening, and we are talking about 900 IMAGES IN the database, but that is not reason I guess because I tried with TOP 10 ALSO.... :))

Thanks guys
cheers